# Get the 1st word of the string with RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the 1st word in a string with RegEx.

I know how to match the 1st word if the 1st chain of characters is a word, but the problem is when my string starts with ; for example.

```
^([\w\-]+)
```

Works with

```
This is my sentence.
```

but does not with

```
; This is my sentence
```

My goal is to match the 1st word

```
This
```

Independently which character(s) is before.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
\b([\w-]+)\b
```

Anchor `^` is a problem which is forcing you to match word only at the begging. That should be replaced by `\b` (word boundary).

Comment: That will match all words in the given text.

Comment: That will return **only first word** in Javascript's `string#match`

Comment: … and it won't using `Regex.Matches` in C#. See where I'm going? No language was specified in the question, so I pointed out the flaws the pattern might have.

Comment: That is the whole point, regex solutions vary a lot with the flavor of regex. If it using Unix tools then even `\b` isn't recognized in ERE. IMHO every question tagged as `regex` must specify the language/tool it is using. There is probably no *pure fit-all type regex*.

Comment: I totally agree, the different flavors vary significantly, which is why knowing the pitfalls is even more important.

Comment: For that matter every answer here has pitfalls because none of these regex will work on awk/sed. I guess you understood my point. An answer may have pitfall ONLY after regex language/tool is known.

Comment: I am using Regex with PHP. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Right, that's why I marked the answer as the good one :) Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try this pattern:

```
^\W*([\w-]+)
```

It is anchored at the beginning of the string (`^`) and allows an arbitrary amount of leading non-word characters (`\W*`) before the first word is matched in the pattern's first group (`([\w-]+)`).

Answer (score 3):

If your language supports lookbehind

```
(?<=^\W*?)([\w\-]+)
```

will match only what you need without playing with groups

Otherwise, Marius Schulz's answer will do the job!